# Is it possible to generate a private key knowing the public key of a signed assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, security

For a signed assembly, using the following code to examine the public key

```
AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllFile);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(an);

if (assembly != null)
{
    AssemblyName asmName = assembly.GetName();
    byte[] key = asmName.GetPublicKey();
    bool isSignedAsm = key.Length > 0;
}
```

Using the byte array for the public key, can an attacker regenerate the private key that is associated with that public key, and create his own set of assemblies that appear to be signed by me?

I want to know this because I want to use the byte array of the public key as a way to prevent loading an assembly that was not signed by a particular private key. (by comparing it to a known public key I already have and trust)

Comment: No they cannot generate the private key from the public key as that's a fundamental part of how public-private key cryptography is used, as long as the key size is large enough to resist a brute-force attack via finding a hash collision.

However, strong names are not designed for security as documented on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx. If you want to protect against your binaries being tampered with, look into Authenticode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: depends how you define able to regenerate the private key. If you don't care about cpu cycles and time then yes, one can always regenerate the private key via brutal force. otherwise no they cant

Comment: I certainly hope not...

Comment: @squillman this actually happened once with MD5

Comment: @MartinCostello so there is no way for them to create an assembly which fools the .NET method AssemblyName.GetPublicKey() into getting the public key I expect - without actually having signed it with the correct public/private key pair?

Comment: @erotavlas There is a way via brute-force, but it likely (but not guaranteed) to be too computationally expensive in terms of time for anyone to bother, unless there was tremendous value in doing so. But like I said, strong-name keys are not a security mechanism as described in the MSDN documentation I provided a link to.

Comment: @MartinCostello well I meant more like simply using the SetPublicKey() method on an assembly I was able to do this after reading the public key and token from the source assembly.  Then I applied those to an imposter assembly I created.